# VB.NET Sending Strings via Postmessage

Tags: vb.net, string, postmessage

OK, this problem has been bugging me for a long time.

I have the code for the service which communicates a string to the client via PostMessage:

```
 Public Sub SendToClient(msgs As String, types As Integer, hwnd As Long)

        postMessage(hwnd, 0, Nothing, msgs)

    End Sub
```

Then I have the client that receives the string:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If (m.Msg = 0) Then
            Dim a as string
            a = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(m.LParam)
           end if
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

However, the client sends an error, or some jumble of binary data or even just a blank string sometimes. By the way, the m.LParam is a number.

Can someone tell me what is the right way to send/receive strings via postmessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
Public Sub SendMessageToApp(ByVal NombreVentana As String, ByVal Mensaje As String, ByVal sender As Form)
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr
        Dim mCopyData As COPYDATASTRUCT

        hWnd = CType(FindWindow(Nothing, NombreVentana), IntPtr)
        Dim message As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        If (CInt(hWnd) <> 0) Then

            message.Append(Mensaje)

            Dim pCopyData As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(message.Length() + 40)


            mCopyData.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message.ToString)
            mCopyData.cbData = message.Length
            mCopyData.dwData = CType(_messageID, IntPtr)
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mCopyData, pCopyData, False)

            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, CInt(sender.Handle), pCopyData)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mCopyData.lpData)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pCopyData)

        End If
    End Sub
```

**Receiver window:**

```
Declarations and definitions:

 Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = 74
    Const SIG_LENGTH As Integer = 36
    Const MAX_COPY_LENGTH As Integer = 128
    Const SigConnect As String = "F7B82657-BD18-4ee6-B182-78721293821C"
    Dim CDCount As Integer

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, _
    ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Dim hWndSender As Integer
    Private Const _messageID As Integer = 10

    'Estructura obligatoria para poder utilizar el API CopyData
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure COPYDATASTRUCT
        Public dwData As IntPtr
        Public cbData As Integer
        Public lpData As IntPtr
    End Structure

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

        If m.Msg = WM_COPYDATA Then
            Dim Estructura As COPYDATASTRUCT
            Dim tipo As Type = Estructura.GetType
            Dim message As String

            Estructura = CType(m.GetLParam(GetType(COPYDATASTRUCT)), COPYDATASTRUCT)

            'Here you get the message
            message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Estructura.lpData, Estructura.cbData)

        End If
```

Comment: I get an 'error creating window handle'. Do you have any simpler code?

Comment: This is the simplest code for sendMEssage, you have to declare the COPYDATASTRUCT structure and declare all the constants. Where are you getting the error? You have to be sure that here:  hWnd = CType(FindWindow(Nothing, NombreVentana), IntPtr), your hWnd have a value. You have to findwindows using the NombreVentana that means "WindowName"

Comment: It uses win32 api at low level so it is user independent. It just sends messages to other window handle